# About continuity of Holder functions

Tags: functional-analysis, continuity

I assume that the functional class $\mathcal{H}^{0}$ is defined as:
In the interval $[x, x + \epsilon]$ it is true that 
$| f(x+ \epsilon) - f(x) | \leq C$ for a positive constant $C$.

Then let the definition of the oscillation about a point be given as
$
\mathrm{osc}[f] (x) : = \lim\limits_{\epsilon \rightarrow 0} \sup_{[x -\epsilon, x + \epsilon]}  f -  \inf_{[x -\epsilon, x + \epsilon]}  f
$.

Then a function $f(x) \in \mathcal{C}^{0} $, $x \in \mathbb{R}$ is continuous about  $x$  if $  {\mathrm{osc}[f](x)}=0$.

Note:

The function $f(x)$ is the mapping $ f: \mathcal{R} \rightarrow  \mathcal{R}  $. Also 
$\epsilon$ and $\mathcal{C}$  do not depend on x.

Question:

Is it true that if $f(x)$ is Holder $\mathcal{H}^{0}$ in the interval $[x, x + \epsilon]$
then  $f(x)$ is discontinuous in this interval?

Comment: Order of your quantifiers is not clear. Do $\epsilon$ and $C$ depend on $x$? And the question looks strange, it seems that there is no relation between Holderness and the class $\mathcal{H}_0$. So of course I can take any smooth function on a compact interval -- it is Holder and belongs to $\mathcal{H}_0$.

Comment: I made some clarifications.

Comment: I would not say it clarifies much. First when you define a class of functions you have to say which functions do you consider. All functions from $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$?  Or functions from a fixed subset of $\mathbb{R}$ to $\mathbb{R}$? Or maybe functions from a Cantor set to itself? It is still not clear why the definition of oscillation appears if you do not use it. Your definition of oscillation at point $x$ does not depend on $\epsilon$ but the definition of the class $\mathcal{H}_0$ does... The letter $\mathcal{C}$ is not defined at all.